# converting a java command line using files as arguments from shell to batch

Tags: java

I am attempting to convert a (working) shell script to a batch file - which is basically a java command line.  The issue appears to be with using a text file ('parameter.txt') containing paths, ports etc as an argument.  (I have left out the setting location lines for clarity)

The two versions are below - along with error reported in the log file.

**SHELL**:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java folder1.classfile folder2/parameter.txt > Logs/log.out 2>&1 & echo $! > Files/pid.txt
```

**BATCH**:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java" -cp folder1.classfile folder2\parameter.txt > Logs\log.out 2>&1 & echo $! > Files/pid.txt
```

**Error**:

> Could not find or load main class folder2\parameter.txt

Comment: You are giving the classpath as `folder1.classfile` and the the class to execute as `folder2\parameter.txt`  Why did you need to add the classpath flag ?

Comment: @jr593 Without the -cp I see the following error:  Error: Could not find or load main class folder1.classfile